# OpenGL in iOS simulator is unusably slow

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, ios-simulator

As per title, simulator is super slow, so my questions is there any way to improve OpenGL performance in iOS simulator?

Comment: Already answered ,see the answer at the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883243/is-there-any-way-to-accelerate-ipad-simulators-opengl-performance

Comment: @manishkumar That answer is quite old though.

Comment: @manishkumar Since the answer was in 2011, I thought that there might be a way to improve that after 8 years :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Simulator supports GPU acceleration for Metal starting with iOS 13 on macOS Catalina. OpenGL ES is still software rendered and is likely to remain that way.

I strongly recommend moving to Metal.